# su another user through ssh with a local script

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, su

I have the following snippet:

```
ssh root@"${DO_DROPLET_IP}" -i "${SSH_PRIVKEY_PATH}" su www -c sh -c -- \
  "./server-user-setup.sh" "${BB_USER}" "${APP_USER}"
```

which is inspired by the following (working) snippet:

```
ssh root@"${DO_DROPLET_IP}" -i "${SSH_PRIVKEY_PATH}" sh -s -- < \
  "./server-root-setup.sh" "${BB_USER}" "${APP_USER}"
```

where both files are **local files**.

However, I can't find a way to quote or escape the top command so that it successfully works. The above throws `${value of BB_USER}": ./server-user-setup.sh: Permission denied`. I have tried many variations:

---

Can anybody explain to me how to quote/escape this command properly?

---

Update: getting promisingly close - this fires the script, but doesn't pass the arguments!

```
ssh root@"${DO_DROPLET_IP}" -i "${SSH_PRIVKEY_PATH}" sh -s -- su www -c < \
  "./server-user-setup.sh" "${BB_USER}" "${APP_USER}"
```

returns

```
server-user-setup.sh: Wrong number of arguments. # Part of the script - no args passed
su www -c ${value of BB_USER} ${value of APP_USER}
```

Comment: Apologies! Local

Comment: Lol yes sorry. End of the day tiredness making me type things incorrectly. I'm sshing as root so no sudo

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want (so only a comment); and I'm not sure it will work; and keep in mind that running random code from the internet is dangerous (especially as root). This madness: `ssh root@"${DO_DROPLET_IP}" -i "${SSH_PRIVKEY_PATH}" 'su www -c "exec sh -s -- '"'${BB_USER}' '${APP_USER}'"'"' <"./server-user-setup.sh"`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That's... wow. I feel a lot better about not getting it. Post it as an answer for others! I'll accept as soon as you do :)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It works correctly! I'll leave it as an edit in the question for somebody, with the answer being rewarded for the proper explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

```
ssh root@"${DO_DROPLET_IP}" -i "${SSH_PRIVKEY_PATH}" \
  'su www -c "exec sh -s -- '"'${BB_USER}' '${APP_USER}'"'"' <"./server-user-setup.sh"
```

Code injection possible via `BB_USER` and `APP_USER` variables.

---

### Long answer

Let's analyze what happens. It's quite complex. For clarity let's assume:

```
DO_DROPLET_IP=ip
SSH_PRIVKEY_PATH=key
BB_USER=b-user
APP_USER=a-user
```

---

#### Original (working) snippet

> ```
> ssh root@"${DO_DROPLET_IP}" -i "${SSH_PRIVKEY_PATH}" sh -s -- < \
>     "./server-root-setup.sh" "${BB_USER}" "${APP_USER}"
> ```

All variables are expanded locally. The redirection is local and [it doesn't matter it's in the middle](https://superuser.com/a/1335355/432690). With our assumed variable values this is the equivalent command:

```
<"./server-root-setup.sh" ssh root@"ip" -i "key" sh -s -- "b-user" "a-user"
```

`ssh` gets these arguments: `root@ip`, `-i`, `key`, `sh`, `-s`, `--`, `b-user`, `a-user`. Since `root@ip` looks like `user@hostname`, the first following argument not recognized as option (like `-i`) or option-argument (like `key` being an option-argument to `-i`) is considered to start an array of operands to build the remote command from. The said argument is `sh` and this is the command `ssh` tries to run on the remote side:

```
sh -s -- b-user a-user
```

This starts `sh` which expects commands from its stdin (due to `-s`). `--` is a POSIX convention that tells the tool anything that follows is not an option (see [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02), guideline 10). This way even if our `${BB_USER}` expanded to `-f` or so, `sh` wouldn't consider it an option. The following operands are set as the positional parameters of the shell (`$1`, `$2`). Stdin is provided by `ssh`, the local file `./server-root-setup.sh` is streamed through.

If the file and the relevant two variables were available on the remote side, you could get (almost) the same result with the following command there:

```
sh "./server-root-setup.sh" ${BB_USER} ${APP_USER}
```

Or if there's a proper shebang in the script:

```
./server-root-setup.sh ${BB_USER} ${APP_USER}
```

So the snippet is indeed a way to run a local script on the remote side. But note I deliberately didn't quote `${BB_USER}` or `${APP_USER}`. In the original snipped they are quoted on the local side, but it doesn't matter because `ssh` builds and passes the command as a *string* to be parsed on the remote side. If any of the two variables contained inner spaces, the remote `sh` would get more arguments than you expected; leading or trailing spaces would be lost. Characters like `$`, `"`, `'` or `\` would cause trouble, unless the variable values were deliberately designed to be parsed (but then they couldn't be used locally to produce an equivalent result, that's why I wrote "almost").

Worse things will happen if e.g. `${APP_USER}` expands to `a-user& rogue_command`. On the remote side you get

```
sh -s -- b-user a-user& rogue_command
```

Note such code injection cannot happen when you run things locally (with or without quotes)

```
./server-root-setup.sh ${BB_USER} ${APP_USER}
```

because separators like `&` and `;` are recognized before variables are expanded, not after. But if you expand variables locally and then the resulting string is parsed again on the remote side, this is a whole different story. It's like remote [`eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/10765659).

I guess `${BB_USER}` and `${APP_USER}` are usernames, quite safe strings, so the whole thing works despite possible general issues. But if these variables are not fully controlled by you, the approach is not safe.

---

#### Your (failed) attempt

> ```
> ssh root@"${DO_DROPLET_IP}" -i "${SSH_PRIVKEY_PATH}" su www -c sh -c -- \
>   "./server-user-setup.sh" "${BB_USER}" "${APP_USER}"
> ```

No redirection this time. Again the variables are expanded locally and the equivalent command looks like this:

```
ssh root@"ip" -i "key" su www -c sh -c -- "./server-user-setup.sh" "b-user" "a-user"
```

`ssh` tries to run this on the remote side:

```
su www -c sh -c -- ./server-user-setup.sh b-user a-user
```

Note all arguments are now arguments to `su`. At this moment `sh` is just an option-argument to `-c` option, similarly `--` is an option-argument to *another* `-c` option (so it doesn't indicate end of options here). My tests show that from multiple `-c` options to `su` only the last one takes effect. This means `-c sh` is discarded, `su` uses whatever shell is specified in the (remote) `/etc/passwd` for the `www` user. This may or may not be `sh`. Let's say it's `some-shell`. This is what's run next (as `www` user):

```
some-shell -c --   # but wait, it's not all
```

with remaining operands of `su`, so

```
some-shell -c -- ./server-user-setup.sh b-user a-user
```

If `some-shell` is a common shell like `sh` or `bash`, it behaves alike. Here `-c` doesn't take an option-argument (see [the specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html)), so `--` does indicate end of options. In this case no following argument can be taken as an option, so we can omit `--`:

```
some-shell -c ./server-user-setup.sh b-user a-user
```

This is like

> ```
> sh -c [-abCefhimnuvx] [-o option]... [+abCefhimnuvx] [+o option]... command_string [command_name [argument...]]
> ```

or (discarding everything we don't use)

```
some-shell -c command_string command_name argument
```

So `./server-user-setup.sh` is *command_string*, `b-user` is *command_name* and `a-user` is *argument*.

> `-c`
>   Read commands from the `command_string` operand. Set the value of special parameter `0` […] from the value of the `command_name` operand and the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, and so on) in sequence from the remaining argument operands. […]

In effect the remote `some-shell` tries to read (source) `./server-user-setup.sh`, with the string `a-user` available as `$1`. Special parameter `0` (now with the value `b-user`) is what the shell considers to be its own name. The name is used in error messages like this one:

> ```
> b-user: ./server-user-setup.sh: Permission denied
> ```

Apparently there is `./server-user-setup.sh` on the remote side but `www` user cannot read it.

---

#### My approach (still unsafe):

```
ssh root@"${DO_DROPLET_IP}" -i "${SSH_PRIVKEY_PATH}" \
  'su www -c "exec sh -s -- '"'${BB_USER}' '${APP_USER}'"'"' <"./server-user-setup.sh"
# 1                         12                          23 3
```

The last line (a comment) is just to enumerate quotes in the previous line. To understand how the command works we need to "decrypt" this quoting frenzy. The important things are:

- Everything inside `1` and `3` single quotes should be taken literally.
- `${BB_USER}` and `${APP_USER}` are in double quotes `2`; "inner" single quotes belong to the quoted string, they don't prevent the variables from expanding.
- Wherever a closing quote immediately precedes an opening quote (e.g. the quotes above `12`), the quoted strings will be concatenated.

Knowing this we can tell the command with expanded variables looks somewhat like this:

```
<"./server-user-setup.sh" ssh root@"ip" -i "key" 'su www -c "exec sh -s -- Xb-userX Xa-userX"'
```

where `X` *denotes* (only for us, here and now) a single quote character that belongs to the string that starts with `su` and ends with the last `"`. Sorry, I couldn't express this in a clearer way. Hopefully it will be less cryptic when we see what `ssh` gets:

`root@ip`, `-i`, `key`, `su www -c "exec sh -s -- 'b-user' 'a-user'"`

The last argument contains double quotes and single quotes. This is exactly the string `ssh` will run on the remote side. Note I took care to pass the whole string as one argument to `ssh`, so the tool doesn't build a string from multiple arguments and spaces; this way I'm in full control over the string. In general this would be important e.g. if `${BB_USER}` expanded to something with a trailing space (the original snippet would fail in this case).

The command that runs on the remote side:

```
su www -c "exec sh -s -- 'b-user' 'a-user'"
```

The behavior of `su` has already been discussed. Note the whole quoted string is an option-argument to `-c`. If not the quote, `-s` would be an option to `su`. This is what runs as `www` user:

```
some-shell -c "exec sh -s -- 'b-user' 'a-user'"
```

Note the quotes in `su` invocation also cause there is no `command_name` and no `argument`(s) (compare `some-shell -c command_string command_name argument` somewhere above). Then `some-shell` just runs:

```
exec sh -s -- 'b-user' 'a-user'
```

This would run without `exec`, but since we don't need `some-shell` anymore, `exec` may be a good idea. It makes `sh` replace `some-shell`, so instead of `some-shell` and `sh` as its child, only `sh` remains, as if when we run `some-shell` we had

```
sh -s -- 'b-user' 'a-user'
```

Now this is very similar to what the original snippet runs (`sh -s -- b-user a-user`). Thanks to additional quotes, possible spaces or few other troublesome characters from `${BB_USER}` or `${APP_USER}` may not break anything. However `'` or `"` will. Code injection is still possible. Consider `${APP_USER}` expanding to `"& rogue_command;"`. The first thing to run on the remote side will be:

```
su www -c "exec sh -s -- 'b-user' '"& rogue_command;"'"
```

It doesn't matter `some-shell` will throw an error, `rogue_command` will run anyway. Make sure your variables expand to safe strings.