# how to grep for “include” and “exclude another term” from file?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to build a grep search that must include the term and exlude another term. I try to use multiple -E "pattern" options but that has not worked.

Here is an example of a command I tried .

```
grep -Ei "\,17\:31" | grep -Eiv "10\.10\.210\.154" file.csv
```

but the output results only match the second constraint grep -Eiv "10.10.210.154"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to find `\,17\:31` but not from IP `10\.10\.210\.154`

You can use this.

```
grep -Ei "\,17\:31" file.csv | grep -Eiv "10\.10\.210\.154"
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Note: [the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1453489/432690) should work but it explains nothing; hence my explanatory answer.</sup>

You told the second `grep` to read `file.csv`, so it does. It ignores its standard input because this is what `grep` does when it operates on file(s).

In effect the second `grep` acts as if the first one wasn't there. It exits after processing the file and printing its output (if any).

The first `grep` awaits input (normally from keyboard, if run in an interactive shell). It can take many lines and even print many (matching) lines to its standard output, until the pipe buffer decides to pass the output to the second `grep`. Then, if the second `grep` is no more, the first `grep` is notified the pipe is broken; it exits.

Or you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to indicate end of input; or you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to kill the first `grep` (and the second, if it's still alive). But this won't fix your data flow.

A proper data flow is like this: you need the first `grep` to read the file, then pipe the result to the second one:

```
grep -Ei "\,17\:31" file.csv | grep -Eiv "10\.10\.210\.154"
# or
<file.csv grep -Ei "\,17\:31" | grep -Eiv "10\.10\.210\.154"
```

The latter syntax has at least one advantage, explained at the end of [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1335355/432690).