# Where is the ambiguous redirect in this bash line?

Tags: linux, bash

When running

```bash
/usr/bin/borg info --last 1 --json ${repo} | jq -r '.archives | first | .end' |  python3 -c "import arrow, sys ; print(arrow.get(sys.stdin.read()).isoformat())" > /etc/local/borg-lastrun-${repo}-${tobackup}.txt
```

I get

```
/etc/local/borg.sh: line 27: /etc/local/borg-lastrun-${repo}-${tobackup}.txt: ambiguous redirect
```

(`${repo}` and `${tobackup}` are set)

**Where is the ambiguity?**

I suspect that this may be the `jq` code (`'.archives | first | .end'`) because of the multiple pipes outside and inside the quotes (?) but I am not sure (nor know how to fix it if this is the case)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think this is because of how spaces were expanded in the (as I said - nonsensical) name and therefore there was a redirection to several files

Comment: @WoJ so did `${repo}` or `${tobackup}` contain a space?

Comment: @raj: yes - both had spaces, quoting `/etc/local/borg-lastrun-${repo}-${tobackup}.txt` immediately revealed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash the value of an unquoted variable (e.g. `${repo}` or `$repo`) undergoes word splitting and filename generation. This means in general an unquoted variable can generate more than one word. Or less; if it's unset or empty then it will generate zero words.

In case of a redirection like `> ${repo}` or `> $repo`, any number of words but one is wrong. Technically the following might be valid (but it's not):

```bash
# wrong
foo='bar baz'
echo qux > $foo
```

*If it was valid*, then the last line would be equivalent to

```bash
echo qux > bar baz
```

which [is valid](https://superuser.com/q/1335333/432690) and equivalent to

```bash
echo qux baz > bar
```

Hiding an argument (here: `baz`) inside what looks like redirection (here: `> $foo`) would be a bad practice if done deliberately, or a potentially harmful bug if done inadvertently. Bash does not let you do this.

<sup>(Actually I *suspect* it's not really because Bash cares, but because of how its parser works: I *think* it recognizes redirections early, separates them from the actual command and processes as somewhat disconnected. Injecting an argument back into the command would be troublesome and not worth the hassle. But this is *my guess*.)</sup>

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections) states explicitly [emphasis mine]:

> The word following the redirection operator […], unless otherwise noted, is subjected to brace expansion, tilde expansion, **parameter expansion**, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, quote removal, **filename expansion, and word splitting. If it expands to more than one word, Bash reports an error.**

This is the "ambiguous redirect" error you got. The manual says "more than one word"; [tests indicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7775870/10765659) the same error occurs in a case of "zero words" (the variable empty or unset).

The right number of words is one. This also applies when there are many variables involved, like in your `/etc/local/borg-lastrun-${repo}-${tobackup}.txt`. This string cannot expand to zero words, but (depending on the values of the variables) it can expand to more than one word. A right way to make sure the string is interpreted as a single word is to double-quote it:

```bash
… > "/etc/local/borg-lastrun-${repo}-${tobackup}.txt"
```

Double-quoting is almost always the right thing to do also in other parts of code, [wherever you use variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). There are [situations where you may omit quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/108618). Situations where you shouldn't quote are relatively rare.

Single-quoting is another way to prevent word splitting, but since it also prevents variable expansion (in fact: any expansion), it's not useful in our case at all.