# Setting environment variables in bash script doesn't work?

Tags: command-line, bash, git, environment-variables

If I run this on the command line, it will make the commit be at the specified date:

```
THE_TIME='2022-01-01T22:50:12 -0700' GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$THE_TIME GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$THE_TIME git commit -am 'commit'
```

However, the moment I put that into a `file.sh` script (chmod 0755), and run it like `./file.sh`, it doesn't seem to pick up those variables. Any ideas how to get the `git commit` command to pick up these temporary environment variables in a bash script?

I have tried 2 things, both which didn't work. Instead of using the specified date, it uses the current date.

First, I tried just doing it like the above but in the script:

```
update() {
  local name="$1"
  echo "$name"
  cd "./$name"
  git add .
  THE_TIME='2022-01-01T22:50:12 -0700' GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$THE_TIME GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$THE_TIME git commit -am 'commit'
  git push
  cd ..
}

update my-repo
update my-second-repo
# ... apply to many repos
```

Second, I tried putting them into a separate file and loading them with `source ./vars.sh`, like this:

```
# vars.sh
THE_TIME='2022-01-01T22:50:12 -0700'
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$THE_TIME
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$THE_TIME
```

```
# script.sh
source ./vars.sh

update() {
  local name="$1"
  echo "$name"
  cd "./$name"
  git add .
  git commit -am 'commit'
  git push
  cd ..
}

update my-repo
update my-second-repo
# ... apply to many repos
```

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't git picking up the environment variables? I am on the latest 13.0.1 Mac OS.

Answer (score 2):

For setting environment variables, as distinct from
local script variables, use the
[export](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/export.1p.html)
command like this:

```
export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$THE_TIME
```

For more information see :

- [Defining a Bash Variable With or Without export](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-variables-export)
- [Working with dates in Git](https://alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git/)

Comment: Fortunately Bash does not split+glob unquoted `$THE_TIME` while parsing this. There are shells that do (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/108618)). To be on the safe side regardless of the shell, it's better to get used to double-quoting variables.

Comment: Also `export` would be invalid for the form of `SOME_ENV=some_val some_command`, so this only applies to the `source` case. (And even if this helps, it'd still be no more than a comment as it doesn't explain why the first case / form does not work for the OP.)

Comment: I don't understand, do I do this in the `vars.sh` file or in the `source.sh` file?

Answer (score 1):

#### Background

There are few things to explain.

Each process has its own environment. The environment contains zero or more environment variables. Each variable is a value (a string) associated to a name (also a string). An instance of a shell (like Bash) is a process, so there is some environment associated to it.

In a shell you can define, access and modify shell variables. Like environment variables, these are strings with names. A given variable is not necessarily in the environment of the shell. When a shell starts, environment variables appear in the shell as shell variables, but then you can create variables that are not in the environment. A variable in the environment of the shell is called "exported variable".

The POSIX shell (`sh`), all (almost-)POSIX-compliant shells (e.g. Bash) and some deliberately-deviating-from-POSIX shells (e.g. Zsh) use the same interface to access environment variables and other shell variables. If you want to get the value of a variable named `foo` from the environment or of a shell variable named `foo` that is not in the environment, you use `$foo`. Note this was a design decision, things could have been designed differently (e.g. [in Python you access environment variables via `os.environ`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4906977/10765659) which is different than accessing "normal" variables like `x`).

If you want to run `something` with `name=value` in its environment, there are several methods:

1. If `name` is *already* exported, you set it to the desired value and then execute `something`:

   ```
   name=value
   something
   ```

   The process will inherit the environment from its parent, i.e. from the shell, thus `name=value` will be in the environment of the process. Note `name=value` will remain in the environment of the shell.
2. Regardless if `name` is in the environment of the shell or not, you can export it, so from now on `name` is in the environment for sure. Obviously you should set the variable to the desired value. All this can be done in two steps:

   ```
   name=value
   export name
   ```

   or in one step:

   ```
   export name=value
   ```

   Then you execute `something`. Like previously, `name=value` will remain in the environment of the shell.

<sup>Note: the methods below should work even if `name` is not in the environment of the shell, so if you want to really test them then you should un-export the variable with `export -n name` (the command is not portable, it works in Bash).</sup>

3. You can tell the shell to execute `something` with `name=value` in the environment, without affecting the environment of the shell:

   ```
   name=value something
   ```

   (Note this is different than `name=value; something`. The latter is equivalent to the method number 1; it will only work if `name` is already exported.)

   It's possible to put more than one variable into the environment of `something`:

   ```
   name=value foo=bar baz=… something
   ```
4. You can run another program that will inherit environment variables from the shell and run `something` with tailored environment. The right program is `env`:

   ```
   env name=value something
   ```

   Like the previous method, this one does not alter the environment of the shell. Here `name=value` is just one of the arguments for `env`, a string that has nothing to do with variables until `env` interprets it. The method may look like a useless longer alternative to the previous one, but it has its advantages:

   - `env` easily allows you to run `something` with `name` *removed* from the environment:

     ```
      env -u name something
     ```

     It's useful when `name` is in the environment of the shell and you want it to stay, still you don't want it in the environment of `something`. Doing this solely in a shell is possible, but somewhat cumbersome.
   - `env` allows you to use names that are valid for environment variables but invalid for shell variables. Example:

     ```
      env b-b=1 something
     ```

     As `env` without arguments prints its own environment, you can test the method really works by running `env b-b=1 env`; in the output you will see `b-b=1`. The previous method (`b-b=1 env`) does not work with this name.

Technical note: when modifying exported variables, un-exporting or exporting, the shell is not obliged to *actually* change its environment. It's enough if it behaves *as if* its environment changed. Therefore statements like "after `export name=value` `name` is in the environment" may or may not be true. "`name` is exported" is a better, stricter term; it means things work as if `name` was in the environment of the shell, even if actually it's not.

---

#### Your specific case

The command that worked for you

> ```
> THE_TIME='2022-01-01T22:50:12 -0700' GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$THE_TIME GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$THE_TIME git commit -am 'commit'
> ```

uses the `name=value something` method. The important fact is `name=value` does not affect the current shell; your `THE_TIME=…` did not affect the shell. In your command `$THE_TIME` later in the line was expanded to the value of the shell variable (exported or not) named `THE_TIME`. Apparently this variable existed at the time and its value was sane in the context of `git`, therefore the command worked and you thought it was good code. The problem is the variable certainly did not come from this very line. Your `THE_TIME=…` only affected what `git` (and possibly its children, if any) saw in its environment.

In the script the same command did not work because `$THE_TIME` expanded to something else; most likely to an empty string due to `THE_TIME` neither having been initiated from the environment nor having been declared in the script.

If you did:

```
THE_TIME='2022-01-01T22:50:12 -0700'; GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$THE_TIME GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$THE_TIME git commit -am 'commit'
#                note the semicolon ^
```

then the shell would interpret `THE_TIME=…;` first and it would set its own variable (exported or not) named `THE_TIME`. The rest of the line would be interpreted later, so both instances of `$THE_TIME` would be expanded as you expect. `THE_TIME` would not get to the environment of `git` though (unless it has been exported earlier).

In your `vars.sh`+`script.sh` try the variables would get to the environment of `git` only if they were already exported, i.e. if you run `script.sh` with variables of the same names in the environment. Their existence in the environment of the shell interpreting the script would make them exported and your assignments would overwrite the values coming from the initial environment with the desired ones.

This did not happen, the relevant variables were not in the environment.

To fix the scripts you should `export` the relevant variables before calling `git`. It doesn't matter if you do it in `vars.sh` or in `script.sh`, because when you `source` one from the other, it's the same shell process that interprets their content.

<sup>Side note: if you `source vars.sh` also from another script and if you `export` the variables in `vars.sh`, then in the other script they will be exported; not exporting in `vars.sh` allows you to independently `export` (or not) the variables in `script.sh` and in the other script.</sup>

An alternative fix is to use the `name=value something` method. Because of `THE_TIME` existing as a shell variable, even your original line would work. Without any `export`, instead of `git commit -am 'commit'` you can do:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$THE_TIME" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$THE_TIME" git commit -am 'commit'
```

And if you also want `THE_TIME` to get to the environment of `git` then you should prepend `THE_TIME="$THE_TIME"` to the line. Alone it looks like a no-op, like assigning the variable to itself, but in `THE_TIME="$THE_TIME" something` it's copying the shell variable (exported or not) to the environment of `something`.

`export`ing is easier, but if you want some variable(s) in the environment of one specific child process (among many) then the alternative fix is useful.

---

#### Notes

- Quoting. IMO it's better [always to double-quote variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618), even if you know [when it's safe not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/108618) and [when it's unsafe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/108618). Scenarios where one mustn't quote are rare (and some of them appear because one doesn't know the right way; [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/108618)), therefore always quoting puts you on the safe side without effort of wondering every time if in this particular case you can get away with omitting quotes or not.

  In the context of your question:

  - `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$THE_TIME` (as a complete command) is safe without double-quotes around `$THE_TIME`. The `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=` part must not be quoted.
  - `export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$THE_TIME` is safe without double-quotes around `$THE_TIME` in Bash, but other shells may split+glob unquoted `$THE_TIME` while parsing this. You may or may not quote `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=`, it's a safe string. Any valid name for a shell variable (plus `=`) is a safe string.
  - `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$THE_TIME something` is safe without double-quotes around `$THE_TIME` in Bash, but other shells may split+glob unquoted `$THE_TIME` while parsing this. The `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=` part must not be quoted.
  - `env GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$THE_TIME something` is *not* safe without double-quotes around `$THE_TIME` in many shells including Bash. You may or may not quote `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=`, it's a safe string. Any valid name for a shell variable (plus `=`) is a safe string, but since with `env` you can create environment variables with other names (e.g. `*`), *in general* you may need to quote the whole `name=value` part.
- Naming. See the paragraph named `TEST.sh` in [this other answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1741190/432690). Use the right [shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87560/108618) (see [what happens with no shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223/108618)) and stop adding this `.sh` to filenames.